# Help me to find convergence interval for series

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{(n+x)^{n}}{n^{n+x}}$$ 
I have tried, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: What is inf above your Sigma.

Comment: It would be great if you state what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{(x+n)^n}{ n^n  }=(1+\frac{x}{n})^n $$

$$\sim e^x \;\;(n\to+\infty) $$

thus the general term of your series is equivalent to

$$\frac {e^x}{n^x} $$

the series converges if only if $x>1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot) it was very helpful